# gulp-watch in combination with gulp-less caching issue

Tags: gulp, less, gulp-watch, gulp-less

I have the following setup:

```
// watch for changes
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./assets/**/*.less', ['compile-less']);
});

gulp.task("compile-less", () => {
    return gulp.src('./assets/build-packages/*.less')
    .pipe($.less({
        paths: [ $.path.join(__dirname, 'less', 'includes') ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(OutputPath)); // ./dist/styles/
});
```

So basically every time a developer changes something in a less file it runs the task 'compile-less'. The task 'compile-less' builds our package less files (including all the @imports). The first change in a random less file works, all the less files are being build. The second time it runs the task but my generated dist folder isn't updated when I change something to a less file that is imported. I'm wondering if the combination of the watch task and the compiling task somehow caches files. Because if I run the compile-less task manually it works everytime.

Does anyone had the same experience?

Comment: If it's the latest `gulp-less 4.0.0` then it's just a bug in `less 3.0.*` it uses. See [gulp-less#283](https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-less/issues/283).

Comment: Oh snap, that's exactly what I'm experiencing. Thanks for the link man!

Answer (score 4):

`gulp-less` version 4.0.0 has a strange caching issue.
Install `gulp-less@3.5.0` and will solve the issue.
This will be fixed. Check out https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-less/issues/283#ref-issue-306992692

Comment: You will also need to install less@2.7.2 since gulp-less v3.5 does not support less v3.0.x.

Comment: did not have any issues with installing a regular less version, then gulp-less@3.5.0 - anyone knows if it installs an older version into gulp-less/node_modules ?

Comment: gulp@3.9.1, gulp-less@3.5.0, less@3.0.1 results in 'Error: less version 3.0.1 is not currently supported'