# Gulp wouldn't watch any changes

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-less

I am scratching my head around but can't seem to figure out whats wrong with the following gulpfile which simply watch and compile less file.

This simply won't watch less changes, I have tried all `gulp`, `gulp watch`. I have to manually run gulp after each change to compile them. Is there something wrong that causing watch to not work as expected?

**Gulp Version**
CLI version 1.4.0
Local version 3.9.1

NPM 4.1.2
Node v7.7.2

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var less = require('gulp-less');

// gulp compile paths

var paths = {
    dist: 'assets/dist'
};

gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src('assets/less/styles.less')
        .pipe(less({
            compress: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist))
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('assets/less/*.less', ['css']);  // Watch all the .less files, then run the less task
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Comment: What version of the gulp do you use?

Comment: @leusrox pls see the edited question, I added the version details there now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gulp-watch in combination with gulp-less caching issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132742/gulp-watch-in-combination-with-gulp-less-caching-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have correct path to the .less files  also you need to add bowersync.reload for it to work.

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('assets/less/*.less', ['css']);
    // init server
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            proxy: "local.build",
            baseDir: appPath.root
        }
    });

    gulp.watch([appPath.root + '**'], browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Comment: Why would I use 'less' when the task name I have is 'css'?

Comment: Sorry , I did not read the task name properly ! Have updated my answer . Thanks